# Reshaping table data into cell of cells of arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, cell-array

I currently need to take four columns of from a table and store this in a `1xheight(table)` cell array with each cell having a `2x1` cell array of `1x2` numeric arrays.

Currently I have the code snippet

```
result=mat2cell(num2cell(reshape(table2array(tab)',2,[])',2),2*ones(1,height(tab)),1)
```

for my table named tab. I fell though as if this is not the best practice of doing this and for the sake of learning and code optimization I'd love to see if this community can help me improve it.

The reason I need this odd structure of data is so that I can efficiently create a struct-array on the form

```
st=struct(...,'LIMITS',result,...);
```

### Example

So this is basically what I wish to do:

```
    tab=array2table(reshape(1:20,4,5)')

tab = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
    ____    ____    ____    ____

     1       2       3       4  
     5       6       7       8  
     9      10      11      12  
    13      14      15      16  
    17      18      19      20  

    result=mat2cell(num2cell(reshape(table2array(tab)',2,[])',2),2*ones(1,height(tab)),1);

    celldisp(result)

result{1}{1} =
     1     2

result{1}{2} =
     3     4

result{2}{1} =
     5     6

result{2}{2} =
     7     8

result{3}{1} =
     9    10

result{3}{2} =
    11    12

result{4}{1} =
    13    14

result{4}{2} =
    15    16

result{5}{1} =
    17    18

result{5}{2} =
    19    20
```